# What is the difference between "batch size in tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array" and "batch size in model.fit"?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, batchsize

As you can see from this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) I'm working on prediction of time series.

I would like to ask the differences between batch size in tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array as in Section 4 in the tutorial and batch size in model.fit. If these two arguments are the same, then what happens if I also write batch size in model.fit ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on `model.fit` located [here.](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)

```
batch_size: Integer or None. A number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, 
batch_size will default to 32. 
Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, generators,
or keras. utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).
```

So do not specify the batch size in `model.fit`